# How to use same Component for routing in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using the same component for my router, on the first click the component affected, but on the next click the component still in the first state.

Here is the script for changing the route

```
<a [routerLink]="['react/1']">link 1</a>
```

```
<a [routerLink]="['react/2']">link 2</a>
```

Here is my router module

**panel-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'
import { PanelCoursesComponent } from 'src/app/components/panel-courses/panel-courses.component';
import { PanelHomeComponent } from 'src/app/components/panel-home/panel-home.component';
import { PanelIntroComponent } from 'src/app/components/panel-intro/panel-intro.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: PanelHomeComponent },
    { path: 'react', component: PanelIntroComponent },
    { path: 'react/:no', component: PanelCoursesComponent } //the target
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PanelRoutingModule { }
```

**panel-course.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-panel-courses',
  templateUrl: './panel-courses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./panel-courses.component.scss']
})
export class PanelCoursesComponent implements OnInit {
  url!: any

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    console.log('route')
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.url = this.router.url
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.params) //the test script
  }

}
```

On the PanelCourseComponent I try to console log the params, but that's only executed one time on the first click.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't the syntax be `[routerLink]="['react' , '1']"` ?

Comment: I have try this, but it still same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `this.route.params.subscribe` method for this case

Here is the example

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params) // It will be executed whenever you click the link
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

by default `pathMatch` is set to `'prefix'`. so paths will be matched against your current location and the first one witch "matches" will render its component. to make your paths match only "exact" match add `pathMatch: 'full'` for your routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: PanelHomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'react', component: PanelIntroComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'react/:no', component: PanelCoursesComponent } //the target
]
```